# How to fix error saying "Task :app:installDebug FAILED", while run my react native project in android studio?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, android-gradle-plugin

I have went through environment setup process same as the react-native doc Linux -> Android..

When I run "react-native run-android", I got the error saying

> Task :app:installDebug FAILED
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Can anyone please help me to sort out this?

This is the error..

```
azran@Azran:~/Desktop/AwesomeProject2$ react-native run-android
info JS server already running.
info Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew app:installDebug)...
> Task :app:installDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
26 actionable tasks: 25 executed, 1 up-to-date
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
error Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

Comment: `com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!`: Check if you have an emulator up and running. If you're using a device, make sure developer mode is enabled in the device and that the PC can use it for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!

This error clearly indicates that no device was found for the app to run. Make sure your emulator was running and if using physical device make sure that **developer mode** and **USB debugging was ON** on the device.

More info at https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app